# Laravel 5.2 : how to set a variable in blade template, without php tags?

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can define a variable using below in blade

```
<?php $var = var1 - var2; ?>
```

and then print it as

```
{{ $var }}
```

**but how to set a variable using laravel blade template method and then use it, basically @set alternative in 5.2?**

Comment: By using the way you said, with php tags. But can't you do it inside your controller?

Comment: yes we can do that, but do you know a way to set a variable in blade template without php tags?

Comment: why don't you do this stuff in controller, i guess controllers are for all calculation/operational stuffs and view is only for display outputs.

Comment: @Hirendrasinh S. Rathod : AGAIN yes we can do that, but do you know a way to set a variable in blade template without php tags?

Comment: no sorry i don't, you should try to ask this question on laracast forum.

Comment: There's no native support for this (to my knowledge) most likely because it's encouraged to set up your variables in the controller not in the view. Why are you doing this in the view, do you have a good reason? The closest thing that I can think of that comes with blade natively is service injection, check out the docs for use: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#service-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this [package for laravel 4](https://github.com/alexdover/blade-set) but it's not compatible with laravel5 due to it's composer file. A quick pull request would fix that.

The main part of the package is only three lines which could be added to your `AppServiceProvider`'s boot method if you didn't want to pull in a package for it:

```
\Blade::extend(function($value, $compiler) {
    $value = preg_replace("/@set\('(.*?)'\,(.*)\)/", '<?php $$1 = $2; ?>', $value); 
    return $value;
});
```

Here's some examples from the readme.

```
@set('my_variable', $existing_variable)
```

You can then use the variable `$my_variable` in the template.

---

You might choose to fetch a bunch of models from your template, for example

```
@set('my_model_list', MyModel::where('something', '=', 1)->paginate(10))
```

Comment: i know that @set works for laravel 4. but it does not work for laravel 5.2.  but as you said it is simple to update, means i need to hack the package ?

Comment: I've added the relevant code to the answer, you should be able to just copy that and add it to your `AppServiceProviders` boot method.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a built in way to do this. Basically, there isn't because you shouldn't. You should either use a view composer, or have it processed elsewhere before it hits your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blade comment syntax

```
{{--*/ $var = $var1 - $var2; /*--}}
{{ $var }}
```

Code above will be translated to following snippet

```
<?php /**/ $var = $var1 - $var2; /**/ ?>
```

Read more: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/256/assigning-a-variable-in-a-blade-template

Comment: isn't the comment syntax was 

{{-- This comment will not be in the rendered HTML --}}

Comment: Yes, see updated post. I was stuck finding the link :/

Comment: aah i see so this is a workaround. but i did not found this in laravel 5.2 docs.

Comment: Yeah, as you stated it -- workaround. You can take a look at the source too https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php#L255

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@if($var=$var1-$var2)@endif
```

and print,

```
{{ $var }}
```